# Creating a database and tables all at once?

Tags: mysql, database-design, create-table

Hey guys I'm creating a quick mysql file to create a DB with some tables in it. I seem to remember that I can create the DB and tables all at once without using the USE my_db though?

Here's what I'm using right now.

```
 CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `preferred_inspections`;
 USE `preferred_inspections`;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_table1`;
    CREATE TABLE `my_table1` (

        `key`                   INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 

        `role`                  VARCHAR(70), 
        `region`                VARCHAR(70),
        `inspection_type`       VARCHAR(70),

        `inspection_number`     SMALLINT,

        `customer_number`       VARCHAR(70),

        `report_date`           DATE DEFAULT NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY(key)

    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_table2`;
    CREATE TABLE `my_table2` (

        `key`                   INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 

        `role`                  VARCHAR(70), 
        `region`                VARCHAR(70),
        `inspection_type`       VARCHAR(70),

        `inspection_number`     SMALLINT,

        `customer_number`       VARCHAR(70),

        `report_date`           DATE DEFAULT NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY(key)

    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

Can't I do something like this though?? I can't seem to remember or find an example....

```
 DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `preferred_inspections`;
 CREATE DATABASE `preferred_inspections` (

    CREATE TABLE `my_table1` (

        `key`                   INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 

        `role`                  VARCHAR(70), 
        `region`                VARCHAR(70),
        `inspection_type`       VARCHAR(70),

        `inspection_number`     SMALLINT,

        `customer_number`       VARCHAR(70),

        `report_date`           DATE DEFAULT NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY(key)

    ),

    CREATE TABLE `my_table2` (

        `key`                   INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 

        `role`                  VARCHAR(70), 
        `region`                VARCHAR(70),
        `inspection_type`       VARCHAR(70),

        `inspection_number`     SMALLINT,

        `customer_number`       VARCHAR(70),

        `report_date`           DATE DEFAULT NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY(key)

    )

)   ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

Thanks Guys n' Gals

Comment: create table my_db.table1 (...

Comment: What is harm with using "use"?

Comment: @Murali No harm, i just had this itching at the back of my brain today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
CREATE TABLE `preferred_inspections`.`my_table1` (
.
.
.
);
```